# How to properly indent in Word merge template?

Tags: ms-word, formatting, mailmerge, mergefield

I have a Word merge template that currently is not indenting properly when a field is too long. Below is an example of the field codes:

```
Gift:   {MERGEFIELD Main_Name} - {MERGEFIELD Main_Amount}
```

When this is used, it will for example display like below if the Main_Name field is too long:

```
Gift:   NameABCDEFGHIJK - 
$1,000
```

When the Main_Name is too long and the Main_Amount has to go onto the second line, I want the Main_Amount to be indented the same as where the Main_Name begins so for example it should look like this:

```
Gift:   NameABCDEFGHIJK - 
        $1,000
```

I tried manually indenting the paragraph of the field codes by lining the Main_Amount up along the Main_Name, but this still doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is not a programming question (it is a simple formatting issue) and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others

Comment: Here is another forum that deals specifically with Mail Merge: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/   .... P.S. Search Google for "hanging indent." Here is my writing on Indents: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Indents